# Why do I need the double dash before argument passed to sh by xargs -I for it to work properly?

Tags: bash, shell, arguments

Here is the command in question

```
 find . -name "*.txt" | xargs -Ifile sh -c 'echo $(basename $1) ' -- file
```

So without the double dash the `file` is not passed to `sh` and then get recognized as `$1`. Why is that? I know that `--` prevents the consequent argument from being recognized as command line options. But since `file` is not prepended with a dash, it seems as though there is no reason for it to get recognized as a command line option.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The first non-option argument to `sh` becomes `$0`. When `sh` is invoked on a script, that's the path to the script. When you run `sh -c SOMECOMMAND`, the shell doesn't use the argument for anything apart from placing into `$0`. Conventionally, it would be a name for the script passed to `-c`, by analogy with the `sh /path/to/script` case where `$0` is the name or path of the script.

Unlike most commands, `--` is treated as an ordinary argument, not as a special-purpose marker. So it's really `--` that's used as `$0` and not the next argument.

```
$ sh -c 'echo $1' hello            

$ sh -c 'echo $0' hello
hello
$ sh -c 'echo $0; echo $1' hello world
hello
world
$ sh -c 'echo $0; echo $1' -- hello
--
hello
```

This has nothing to do with `xargs`, it's passing all of the arguments after `sh` to the `sh` command.

Comment: What's the "name" here?

Comment: @Melab I meant the argument. It's conventionally a name for the `-c` script. I've edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

In the above example the `--` is acting as a blocker between `sh -c 'echo $(basename $1) '` and `file`. it's forcing the string `file` to be the `$1` argument to `sh`.

The above could've been streamlined to this:

```
$ find . -name "*.txt" | xargs -Ifile sh -c 'echo $(basename file) '
```